# Flex 4/Air setting bounds for WindowedApplication

Tags: apache-flex, air

for some reason this flex 4 code gives me an error but I can't figure out why.  In my `WindowedApplication` I have:

```
var prefs:Object = fs.readObject();
fs.close();
var rect:Rectangle = new Rectangle();
rect = prefs.bounds as Rectangle;
this.bounds = rect;  // error here
```

> Error message:
>   ArgumentError: Error #2007: Parameter rect must be non-null.

I originally also tried it without the rect object and just did:

```
this.bounds = prefs.bounds as Rectangle;
```

which gives me the following error:

> TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert Object@1dbbe1f1 to flash.geom.Rectangle.

That seems like a bogus error since I can assign pref.bounds to rect without an error.  I don't know why this isn't working.  It works under flex 3 compatibility mode but that also breaks a lot of my spark components so I can't use it.

Answer (score 0):

```
rect = prefs.bounds as Rectangle;
```

`rect` ends up as `null` because `prefs.bounds` is not an instance of `Rectangle` class. Casting with `as` keywords returns `null` if it fails.

Just give a `trace(prefs.bounds);` after the call to `readObject` to see what it contains.

---

Update:

The fact that the value in `prefs.bounds` have x, y, width and height properties, doesn't make it a `Rectangle` object - it is just an object with those four properties. The easy solution is to create a `Rectangle` object from those values and use that:

```
var prefs:Object = fs.readObject();
var rect:Rectangle = new Rectangle(prefs.bounds.x, prefs.bounds.y, prefs.width, prefs.height);
this.bounds = rect;
```

If you call [registerClassAlias](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/net/package.html#registerClassAlias()) before writing the rectangle object to the file stream, the `readObject` would return an object of appropriate type instead of a generic one.

```
registerClassAlias("flash.geom.Rectangle", Rectangle);
fs.writeObject(this.bounds);

//later...
//Casting with () will throw an error if the read object is not a Rectangle
var rect:Rectangle = Rectangle(fs.readObject());
trace(rect);
```

Comment: so you're saying that:

this.bounds = rect; 

equates to:

this.bounds = null;

And the windowedApp doesn't accept that? 

When I use the debugger, prefs.bound has all of the fields you'd expect, width, height, x, y, etc.  So if it's not a Rectangle, I don't know what it would be.

The prefs object by the way is actually generated originally from this.bounds and saved to a file.  That's why when I read it back with this code, I am surprised it is choking like this.

Comment: Hey thanks for the great responses.  Unfortunately, the code doesn't work.

var rect:Rectangle = Rectangle(fs.readObject());
trace(rect);

gives me the error:

TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert Object@1db7bdf9 to flash.geom.Rectangle.

Even though I use:

registerClassAlias("flash.geom.Rectangle", Rectangle);
fs.writeObject(this.bounds);

to save it initially.

I just don't understand why AIR can't do this kind of 1:1 conversion.  This code is actually taken from an app in Flex 3 and it worked perfectly there.  I just don't know what has changed in Flex 4.

Comment: Hey, actually, I tried it again, and it works!

What I was missing was this line in the init() method:

flash.net.registerClassAlias("flash.geom.Rectangle", flash.geom.Rectangle);

I think putting it there meant that it worked for both WRITE and READ operations.

Thanks for the help!